# Storing Rails 3 Routes in Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

By question is actually pretty simple. I'd just like to know if anybody was able to load their Rails 3 routes into a database so that they could be manipulated without server access from an admin panel like Typus. If anyone has pulled this off or knows of an effective way to do it, please let me know as I am really curious to pull this off on Rails 3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may have to handle your own dispatching with a route like `"*path"`.  Then `/foo/bar/123` would route to a controller of your choice where `params[:path]` is an array `['foo', 'bar', '123']`.  Then you could do whatever from there.

Comment: Now that's a good idea. And then if I had a controller handling dispatching I could query a database to check for routes from there. Would query caching be the best way to cache the database held routes?

Comment: Not sure.  I'd say get it working first, then worry about performance if simple DB queries on every request is actually a performance bottle neck.  My guess is that it won't be.